# Will Windows 10 reset mess up Linux partitions

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning

I have a fairly new computer that came with Windows 10 preinstalled. Currently, I dual boot Windows 10 with Linux. If I reset Windows 10 (I use the option 'Reset and keep files'), will it mess with my Linux partition? Also, will the Windows 10 reset reinstall the windows bootloader, or will it leave grub alone?
Edit:
My Windows partition, the Linux partition, and the recovery partitions are all on the same drive.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the Linux Partitions located on the same drive also 
are you using an Windows recovery partition to recover the PC?

Comment: I edited the question. See edits.

Comment: No; it only effects the system partition

Comment: You're treading waters you aren't quite sure about. As such, back everything up.